# How to parse object during asynchronously processing function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, seq

What should I do in case when  I want to call seqEach on two_objects:

```
Seq()
    .seq(function() {
      pivotal.getProjects(this);
    })
    .flatten()
    .seqEach(function(data) {
      var project_ids = data.project.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x.id); })
      console.log('project_ids: '.red + project_ids );
      // pivotal.getStories(project.id, { filter: "state:finished" }, this);
    })
    .seq(function() {
        var aggregatedStories = [];
        Hash.map(this.args, (function(arg) {
            aggregatedStories.push(arg[0]);
        }));
        res.send(aggregatedStories);
    });
```

Logs:

```
project_ids: 644511,340755
```

`pivotal.getProjects(this);`

returns something like

`{"project": { "id": 644511}, { "id": 340755}  }`

So problem is because `data` should be replaced by `data.project` but how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So problem is because `data` should be replaced by `data.project` but how to do it?

Either you add the line `data = data.project;` on top of your `seqEach` callback, or you inject a mapping function like

```
.map(function(d) { return d.project; })
```

into your chain. Or you just change the `pivotal.getProjects` method…